# Display Images from Windows Folder in SSRS Report

Tags: image, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, bids

I'm trying to make a report in BIDS (2008) that will include external images. We want to use the report to proof the images & other info before we approve our flyer for printing. I've done a bit of searching, but haven't gotten the help I need yet. The path to the images will be image specific, like "\\NETWORKSERVER\ServerD\Docs\Flyer's Images\Quarterly Flyer\ImageName.png"  The URL works fine when I paste it in the search bar of my local pc or the server that has BIDS installed on it, but the report will not display the image. When I add an image to the textbox, how do I set it up so that it displays the image when I run the report? The images are on a different server than the reporting server.

Comment: Just tried your answer, Daniel, and it worked just like I wanted it to. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible but you will just have to format the link correctly and ensure that the execution account for the SSRS server actual has access to that network location.

```
="file://\\NETWORKSERVER\ServerD\Docs\...\ImageName.jpg"
```